# Android SQLite query with integer parameter

Tags: android, sqlite

The [documentation for SQLiteDatabase.query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) says that the `selectionArgs` will be bound as strings.

What is the recommended way to perform a query with an integer parameter?

Is it this:

```
int value = 10;
Cursor cursor = database.query(
    "TABLE_X", 
    new String[] { "COLUMN_A", "COLUMN_B" },
    "COLUMN_C = " + value,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null);
```

Or is it this:

```
int value = 10;
Cursor cursor = database.query(
    "TABLE_X", 
    new String[] { "COLUMN_A", "COLUMN_B" },
    "COLUMN_C = ?",
    new String[] { Integer.toString(value) },
    null,
    null,
    null);
```

Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second option with `?` is the suggested way of using **query** method.

> **selectionArgs**: You may include ?s in selection, which will be replaced by the values
>   from selectionArgs, in order that they appear in the selection. The
>   values will be bound as Strings.