# SQLite DB select method with different types in where clause

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following code that works and gets a record from a database.

```
public Audit getAudit(SQLiteDatabase db, String projectId, String date,String type, int category) {
    String[] columns = { "user_id", "submitted", "answers" };
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{projectId, date, type};

    Cursor c = db.query("AUDITS", columns, "project_id = ? AND date = ? AND type = ?",whereArgs, null, null, null);
    if (c != null)
    {
        Audit audit = new Audit(projectId, type, category, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("user_id")), date, c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("submitted")), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("user_id")));
        return  audit;
    }
    return null;
}
```

But now I want to add another column to the Where clause, and this column holds an integer and not a string. So I can not add it to `whereArgs` array which holds strings. Is there a way that I can still use this method with mixing types or do I need to just do a raw query??

Comment: Well yes I tried and I got a compile error, I think that whereArgs holds the values that I need to find in the columns, not the column names. So most columns hold a Strings, but one holds an Integer.

Comment: I tried this now:                                                                                    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{projectId, date, type, Integer.toString(category)};

Comment: ok, I thought it would but I just checked again, Android Studio is giving me an incompatible types error when I don't convert `category`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Integer.toString() way seems to be best as "the values will be bound as Strings" in the query method. See the answer to 
[Android SQLite query with integer parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222714/android-sqlite-query-with-integer-parameter)

Comment: Yes as I mentioned I did do that and it worked. thaks